# Using the Throwable class

Tags: java, exception, throwable

I know that each java class should extend the Throwable class so that exceptions can be handled. Is this done by:

```
public class Test extends Throwable
```

or

```
public class Test throws Throwable?
```

Comment: Where did you read this?

Comment: _What_?  This is completely nonsensical.

Comment: Your information is very, very wrong. If you want to learn how to handle (and throw) exceptions, I'd check out the tutorial on Oracle's site: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/ (and in particular the section about [handling exceptions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/handling.html))

Comment: i already read it but it did not help me with this. my lecturer's notes have that in Java to catch exceptions you need to extend the throwable class

Comment: quoted: " Primitive types, or object whose class doesn’t extend Throwable cannot be thrown as exceptions."

Comment: @user3126119 That statement is correct, but you have misread it.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik can you explain please

Comment: @user3126119 Your comment, and the statement in your question have 2 different meanings. Anyways, yes that is true.

Comment: **Throwing** an exception is very different from **handling** it. That's like saying that a catcher in baseball needs a ball in order to catch a ball. He doesn't need a ball, he needs a glove. To handle an exception, you don't extend `Throwable`, you write a `try-catch` block.

Answer (score 3):

> Primitive types, or object whose class doesn’t extend Throwable cannot be thrown as exceptions.

Interpretation:

```
throw 3;
```

doesn't work because 3 is a primitive type.

```
throw new String();
```

doesn't work because `String` doesn't extend `Throwable`.

```
throw new RuntimeException();
```

works because `RuntimeException` is a subclass of `Throwable`.

Comment: Actually you can `throw null` which will do what you expect :)

Comment: @AdamGent `null`'s type, also called `null` by the specification, is by definition the subtype of all reference types, which includes `Throwable`.

Comment: one thing, ...so when do you use extends Throwable?

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I'm familiar with that. Others are not I'm sure :)

Comment: @user3126119 You never need to, or should, use `extends Throwable` directly. If you create your own exception class (rarely needed), then you'll have `extends RuntimeException` or, possibly, `extends Exception`.

Comment: @AdamGent I don't know if it does the expected---it doesn't throw the `null` :)

Comment: Well null does extend NPE. It is an oddity. I only pointed it out because I find it amusing.. even though I loathe `null`.

Comment: @AdamGent But are you aware that `throw null` actually completes abruptly, failing with a `NullPointerException`? So the `throw` statement itself doesn't get to throw anything.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik its been awhile since I ran into the use case but I thought for some reason that not to be true. That is the bytecode generated was the same or for some reason throwing `null` was/is more efficient. I can't remember which one but there is actual old Sun code out there that throws null.

Comment: @AdamGent The bytecode sure says "throw null" but that instruction fails at runtime. It never gets to throw null because it completes abruptly.

Comment: JLS to the rescue! Section [14.18](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.18): "If evaluation of the Expression completes normally, producing a null value, then an instance V' of class NullPointerException is created and thrown instead of null. The throw statement then completes abruptly, the reason being a throw with value V'." (That said, a `throw` _always_ completes abruptly, so that's not the reason it never throws null.)

Comment: In theory throwing `null` might have been more efficient NPE (as noted by Peter http://stackoverflow.com/a/6591924/318174). I don't recall where I saw it and I can't seem to google the code.

Comment: @yshavit That's what I went to check out. It's difficult to talk about normal completion when dealing with the `throw` statement :) So I would say that it completes abruptly squared when you throw a null :)

Comment: @AdamGent No chance it's more efficient. Both instantiate an `NPE`.

Comment: The NPEs in those two cases are for different reasons, @AdamGent. The `i.intValue` one throws NPE because the throws expression completes abruptly (the first bullet point in the part of 14.18 that I quoted above). The second throws NPE because the throws expression completes normally but has a null value (the third bullet point, which I quoted). The stack traces would be different.

Comment: I did say *might have been* (Like ancient JDKs) more efficient and I know it results in two different stack traces now. I really have no idea why some one would write `throw null;` but it was in some ancient  Sun code.

Comment: @AdamGent yshavit is talking about the code in Peter's answer. `throw null` and `throw new NullPointerException()` are completely indistinguishable.

Answer (score 0):

When a class extends a Throwable, the class is a sub-class of Throwable and you can throw this class as a Throwable anywhere in you code.

```
class MyCoolThrowable extends Throwable{

  try {
  //... some error ...
  } catch (MyCoolThroable t) {
  //... handle the throwable
  }
}
```

You add *throws Throwable* to a constructor or method so that the code that calls your constructor/method will be forced to use try-catch

```
void mySweetMethod() throws Throwable {
  //...
}

try {
  mySweetMethod();
} catch(Throwable t) {
  //... handle it here
}
```

I think this clarified what you have read:)

Comment: `Throwable` is not an interface.

Comment: You can't throw it anywhere in the code -- only from methods that declare `throws Throwable` (which they should almost never do) or in `try` blocks that include a `catch (Throwable t)` (which you should almost never write). If you want to throw it from anywhere, you should extend `RuntimeException`.

Answer (score 0):

> I know that each java class should extend the Throwable class so that exceptions can be handled.

No, someone ***lied*** to you.

To handle exceptions, you need to keep in mind two things:

- If it's a **checked** exception, then the class will refuse to compile if there is not a `try...catch` block wrapping the dodgy code, or if you don't declare the exception to be thrown.

  ```
  try {
      File f = new File("Foo.txt");
  } catch (FileNotFoundException f) {
      System.out.println("File doesn't exist!");
  }
  ```

  or:

  ```
  public void doDodgyStuffWithFile throws FileNotFoundException { }
  ```
- If it is an **unchecked** exception, then you will not get a compile-time failure for not catching the dodgy code, but you *may* get runtime exceptions from it.

  ```
  String input = scanner.nextLine();
  System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(input));
  ```

If you are *throwing* or *catching* the exception, **be as specific as possible.**  Do not give into the temptation to throw/catch `Exception`, and [**never catch a `Throwable`**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17334093/1079354).